# Slowing down redis via proxy

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, microservices, load-testing

for some load/chaos testing on a java springboot microservice, i'm trying to slow down dependencies, including redis.

I use `toxiproxy` to inject latencies on downstream calls (soap, rest, sql db, etc) and it all behaves.

I want to do the same thing with redis. Basically, making sure a read or a write takes 10 seconds from java.

The thing is if i add a slow proxy in front of the sentinel port, it has no effect.

If i add a slow proxy in front of the server, it has no effect either.

- Sentinel is on 26000
- Server is on 6379
- "slowed-down" server is on 6377

I can check with `redis-cli -p 6377` and all read/write calls are definitely taking 10 seconds

But from the java app, no effect whatsoever.

I Tried different `application.properties` combinations of this but it had zero effect.

```
spring.redis.sentinel.master=mymaster
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes=localhost:26000
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=localhost:6377
```

What did i miss? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue with Redis is that during cluster initialization, when getting/initializing the partitions, Redis uses an iterator to call hasnext which returns the original ports rather than toxiproxy ports so the redis client gets initialized with the working ports.

The workaround I did was to explicitly set the uris after the cluster client initializes. And also remove the refresh so that the cluster doesn't try to get the original ports again